# Firebase Firestore and Storage: How to delete data every time it is read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, delete-file

I'm making a messaging app. I wanted to build a backend similar to What's app. So I wanted the database (firestore and storage) to works as a buffer, ie it only keeps the data until the interested users read the messages / files. How can I intelligently accomplish this?

I had two ideas:

1. Use a frebase cloud function that deleted messages every hour. But this creates two problems for me: if the chat buckets are thousands, how much work does this function have to do? Even if the function scales out, how would it coordinate with others that would do the same job as it? Also how do I tell it to delete a message only when it has been read?
2. The one I will probably use: every message has a sending timestamp. When the user reads the messages it simultaneously launches a delete request for all messages with timestamp <= NOW. The problem is that each reading will correspond to an elimination. Is it expensive? Is it slow? Also if the message contains references to storage (eg audio) I will also have to delete that.

Does anyone have a better strategy? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature built into Firestore to automatically delete documents as they are read, so you will have to implement this in your application logic yourself.

The most common approaches are:

1. Periodically run a cleanup process that deletes outdated content based on a timestamp in each document. You'd typically run this with a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), as that allows you to control how many (and how often) cleanup processes run. Since you're querying with a timestamp here, the number of documents you read (and hence that you pay for) is exactly the same as the number of documents you need to delete.
2. Implement a time-to-live on documents, that automatically deletes them after a certain time period. You can use Cloud Tasks for this, which means your Cloud Function gets triggered for each individual document that needs to be deleted. This saves you a read of that document, but add the complexity of adding Cloud Taskjs. Doug Stevenson wrote a great blog post on this: [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)

Comment: OK thank you very much. As for your first solution (which corresponds to my first one) if I have 100K buckets where each bucket contains a collection of message documents, does a scheduler type function require a lot of resources? Is only one enough or other Xs are automatically created that do this check in parallel?

PS: how do you personally see my second proposal? I mean my second option, to send a delete request every time a mex is read.

Comment: The scheduled function doesn't require much resources, but your code in it may. I recommend trying it with a local Node.js script first. If that takes a lot of time, and API calls, so will it in a scheduled Cloud Function.